# PHP Warning: Undefined array key (isset)

Tags: php, html

I receive this error inside the error_log. When I do a search on Google they recommend adding "isset" function.

```
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "h" in /path-to-script/script.php on line 452
```

This is line 452:

```
if ($maxitems == 0 || ($count['h'] > $min && $count['h'] < $max)) $b['h'] .= '<div class="itembox">... {html}
```

I tried to add "isset" the following way:

```
if ($maxitems == 0 || (isset($count['h']) > $min && isset($count['h']) < $max)) $b['h'] .= '<div class="itembox">...
```

After adding "isset" the error goes away, but the items don't show on the webpage, so basically it breaks something.

It is a PHP script to gather some JSON via API and show the items on the web.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean - so the comparison is now comparing true/false with min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()` in a way something like this

```php
if ($maxitems == 0 || (isset($count['h']) && $count['h'] > $min && $count['h'] < $max)) {
    $b['h'] .= '<div class="itembox">... {html} ... </div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply, tried this code as well, the site keeps working fine, same as before, but I still get the same error on that line: "PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "h" in /path-to-script/script.php on line 452".